# File length in audio classification

Tags: audio-recognition

I am dealing with audio data with samples as long as 20 min. I was wondering if I can use their spectrograms as input for Resnet18 or is it better to split them to obtain files with smaller size. Does anyone have experience with classification of such long audio files? What be the disadvantages if any?

Comment: What kind of MP3 input do you receive? Phone conversations? Sitcom dialogue? Live music performances? On a timescale of tens of minutes, is the generating process likely to change, e.g. a new speaker joins the conversation, or TV channel is flipped / scene changes / commercial break, musicians begin playing a new song. What classification output do you produce? A single number for the whole twenty-minute sample? New classifications every thirty seconds? How do you assess model errors?